# c# reference to reference

Tags: c#, reference

Is there any way to do the following in C#?

```
List<int> aList = new List<int>();
List<int> bList = new List<int>();
... // fill the list somehow
List<int> referece; //?????
if (doThis)
    referece = aList;
else
    referece = bList;

reference= .... assign another list to reference
```

Is this possible in C#? In C++ I would take a referece to a list, but in c#?

---

EDITED:
I corrected my example. The think is, I want to replace the list with a new/differen list and I want to change aList or bList.
When I assign a new list to reference, aList and bList do not change. But that's what I really want, change aList or bList. reference is just to select the variable that holds the list.

Comment: If `DoSomethingWithSelectedList` were actually a method, this would work exactly as coded

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Where is the problem?

```
List<int> aList = new List<int>();
List<int> bList = new List<int>();
... // fill the list somehow
List<int> referece = null;
if (doThis)
    referece = aList;
else
    referece = bList;

if(reference != null)
    reference.DoSomethingWithSelectedList();
```

`List<T>` is class (refrence type), so any variable of type `List<T>` is a refrence to an object of class `List<T>`.

Comment: A question not an answer and the problem is there is no DoSomethingWithSelectedList on List<int>

Comment: @PeterRitchie: you're fast ... and DoSomethingWithSelectedList() on List<int> is exactly the same problem as in C++!

Comment: DoSomethingWithSelectedList() is for instance Clear(), AddRange()...
The thing is, that I want aList or bList do be changed. reference is only to select the list that I want to manipulate.

Comment: @bebo: i got that, you'll be fine with any instance method of List<T>.

Answer (score 1):

You need an extension method on `List<int>` something like below:

```
 public static void DoSomethingWithSelectedList(this List<int> myList)
        {
            // your code
        }
```

and List is a reference type in c#.

Answer (score 0):

You should design your own list, not deriving from List but implementing ICollection interface adding all methods you need